# How to make an input range slider span an octave(s) when triggering oscillator

Tags: web-audio-api

I don't understand how to programmatically hitch the formula 440×2n/12 to the input range slider to set the frequency of an oscillator in 12 step western scale increments. I set the range slider from 1 to 12.

This is as far as I've made it..blah.

```
<input id='input' type='range' min='1' max = '12' step=''></input>

oscillator.frequency.value = ($('#input').val() //(math stuff);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**

```
<input id='input' type='range' min='100' max = '1200' step='100'></input>


    oscillator.frequency.value =  440  ;   
    oscillator.detune.value = $('#input').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's far, far easier to do this using "detune".  Set the frequency value to whatever base note you want (A-440 is a fine choice) and then also set detune in cents - each note in the chromatic scale is +/- 100 cents.

Comment: I read the other thread where you mentioned this. I didn't 'get it' until reading it now. I'll experiment. Thanks Chris.